# Default style for page from codebehind

Tags: wpf, xaml

How can I set style to all elements on page to default from code.

```
Page.Style = null
```

This variant dosent work.

Comment: How you try this: for each element in the visual tree, set Style to null? There are plenty of samples showing how to traverse the Visual Tree on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @kennyzx for example?